# How to uninstall Budgie Desktop

Tags: uninstall, budgie

I installed Budgie Desktop on my laptop and now i want to uninstall it from my computer and does anyone know how to uninstall it ? and also bluetooth isn't working on my laptop ...

Answer (score 2):

Test this:

`Switch on` your computer.

Press and hold the `Shift` key, which will bring up the `Grub` menu.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `recovery mode`.

Your pc should display a menu with a number of options.

Select the line ending with `Drop to root shell prompt`.

In the terminal run

```
sudo -i
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan ppa-purge

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(budgie),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'

apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get dist-upgrade
ppa-purge ppa:evolve-os/ppa
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```