# Remove Budgie desktop in 18.04

Tags: desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome, budgie

I have had Budgie installed since 16.10, and now I'd like to remove it. The instructions in the answer to [Completely remove Budgie](https://askubuntu.com/q/961580/364597) are for a system with several desktops installed. The answer to [How to uninstall Budgie Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/q/647523/364597) is for a version of Ubuntu before it came with Gnome. I just updated to 18.04.

I'm a simple user. I can follow the logic of the instructions of the 2nd linked question above on how to get to the Grub menu and open a terminal there, and I already looked at an article that explained the first few lines of the code that follows that - mounting the drives so they can be written to, updating.

I get lost at `apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan ppa-purge`.

Should I follow those previous instructions to remove Budgie and switch to Gnome, or is it different now?

Comment: Check out my recent answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1140803/953003). Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Start in text-only mode

- Switch on your computer. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading,
  and press and hold Shift, which will bring up the Grub menu.
- Select the line which starts with Advanced options.
- Select the line ending with (recovery mode)
- Press Return and your machine will begin the boot process.
- After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options, including Drop to root shell prompt. Press Return with this option highlighted.

  The PC will start in a terminal. Run these commands:

Mount partitions in read-write mode

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
```

**Edited on 20-05-2018**

Start networking:

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

Update repositories

```
apt update
```

Install aptitude and deborphan

```
apt install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
```

Eliminate the components of budgie that are not necessary in Ubuntu

```
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(budgie),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
```

Reinstall ubuntu-desktop

```
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Eliminate orphan packages

```
deborphan
apt --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
```

Remove unnecessary packages

```
apt autoremove
```

Remove downloaded packages

```
apt clean
```

Restart system

```
reboot
```

When restarting, remove the budgie ppa.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:budgie-remix/ppa
or
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntubudgie/backports
```

Comment: Thanks - it helps me out to have an explanation for what is happening. It is easy to follow this way too.

Comment: The system couldn't download anything. Can it normally download in recovery mode?

Comment: Run:  to start networking - systemctl enable NetworkManager.service - systemctl start NetworkManager.service